# How to use wildcards to match directory paths in Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-store-apps, sqlite.net

I have a db containing folder paths and I'd like to find all folders contained by some folder. I get partial results with:

```
select * from pathTable where Path like ?||'%'
```

Given

```
c:\\root\\1
c:\\root\\1 Copy
c:\\root\\1\\2
c:\\root\\1\\3\\3a
c:\\root\\1\\4
```

When ? is "c:\\root\\1", the above query returns

```
c:\\root\\1
c:\\root\\1 Copy
```

I would like to get all subfolders too. I suspect the Sqlite is stumbling on the '\' in the stored paths. Anyone know what I've done wrong?

Comment: Try adding another wildcard like select * from pathTable where Path like ?||'%\\%'. I believe you will need to escape the "\", but I don't have SQL Lite loaded so cannot check.

Comment: I can see how that would get the next level of folder, but I'm hoping for something that will go n levels deep.

Comment: I have created the table and data the way you have it above. The query runs command line and returns all results with the query you have. So, I suspect we may have an issue at the c# layer. Trying that now.

Comment: Can you post the code you are calling to 1) build the string 2) execute the sql? I get different results in C# depending on how I send the parameter.

Comment: Absolutely, but not until late tonight. You're going above and beyond here- pointing out that the problem is probably at the C# layer is already quite helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I had to do to allow the string parameter to be "fully" escaped via the @ symbol.

```
void printPaths()
    {
        string mypath = @"c:\\root\\1";
        string sql = ("select * from paths where pathdesc like @mypath");

        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql,m_dbConnection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mypath", mypath+"%");

        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
            Console.WriteLine("ID: " + reader["pathid"] + "\tpathdesc: " + reader["pathdesc"]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```